# How to deploy a react.js based SPA to Azure App Service + CDN?

Tags: azure, reactjs, azure-web-app-service, single-page-application, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating a react.js based SPA, and I'll have a landing page on launch. The static landing page should have an action button that directs to the full SPA.

For AWS, I realized it's done by simply using S3 and Cloudfront, and Cloudfront also allows routing to custom error page on 404. This means no server code is needed to handle this, and it may free up some server resources?

For Azure, however, I'm unsure of how to mimic such an architecture. I'm guessing I should use Blob storage to store the SPA and the landing page, but how would I be able to mimic the abilities of Cloudfront? Is Azure CDN sufficient? Thanks!

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/11/28/creating-an-angularjs-single-page-application-with-routes-on-azure-webapps/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure CDN supports to cache Web Apps.

You can build up a simple Azure Web App with your SPA and custom routing rules and the 404 error page. Then create the Azure CDN, configure the `Origin type` to `web app`, and select or type your origin domain in the Origin hostname dropdown.

[image]

You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-create-new-endpoint/ for the detailed steps.